# Finding roots for a Lie algebra g, wrt toral subalgebra h

Tags: matrices, lie-algebras

I'm trying to find the root space decomposition of a lie algebra wrt a toral subalgebra h.  Both a matrix lie algebras.  I'm confused about how do I find the linear forms $\lambda \in \mathfrak{h}^*$ on $\mathfrak{h}$.

$\mathfrak{g}_{\lambda } {\text{:=} \{ X\in \mathfrak{g}|\text{ad}_H(X).=\lambda (H)X \forall H\in \mathfrak{h} \} } $

So the above formula for the root space is simple enough, but how do I find all the $\lambda$ such that $\mathfrak{g}_{\lambda }$ is nonzero?

In my example, $\mathfrak{h}= \{ \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & u & 0 & 0 \\
 -u & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & v \\
 0 & 0 & -v & 0
\end{array}
\right) | u,v \in \mathbb{C} \}$ and $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{so_4}\mathbb{C}$ but I'm looking for more general help on how to find all the elements of $\mathfrak{h}^*$ that give nonzero root spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a better way, but one way is to write a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$ and a basis ${ h_1, h_2}$for $\mathfrak{h}$ and then create the matrix for each $Ad_{h_i}$ in the basis of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Then, one solves the usual eigenvalue problem for both of the $Ad_{h_i}$.  Since $Ad_{h_1}$ and $Ad_{h_2}$ commute, you will end up finding they have a common eigenspaces.  Then, reading off the eigenvalues for the common eigenspaces and using linearity gives the $\lambda$ functionals.

I don't have my copy of Fulton and Harris's Representation Theory book handy, but they might even work this out as an example.  At the very least, they'd work out *some* example, which may give you better tools to work with than the one I've described.

*Edit*

Here is a start on working it out.  Let $h_1 = E_{12}$, the matrix with a 1 in the $1,2$ slot an a zero else.  Let $h_2 = E_{34}$.

Consider the matrix $X = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & a & b \\ 0 & 0 & c & d \\ -a & -b & 0 & 0 \\ -b & -d & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ in $\mathfrak{g}$.  (I've set the entries corresponding to $\mathfrak{h}$ equal to 0 because we know what $Ad_{h_i}$ does to those).  To simplify notation, I'll only describe the top right 2 x 2 block at all times.  The top left and bottom right 2 x 2 blocks are always 0s, while the bottom left 2 x 2 block is always whatever is necessary to guarantee I'm looking at an element of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Computing, one finds $$ Ad_{h_1}X = \begin{bmatrix}  c & d \\ -a & -b\end{bmatrix}$$ (meaning, by the above convention, that the bottom left is what it needs to be to make $Ad_{h_1}X$ antisymmetric and the top left and bottom right are both 0s).

In order for $X$ to be an eigenvector of $Ad_{h_i}$ with eigenvalue $\eta$, we must have $$\begin{align}
 c &=& \eta a \\ d &=& \eta b\\ -a &=& \eta c\\ -b &=& \eta d\end{align}$$ simultaneously holding.

This implies that $\eta = \pm i$.  When $\eta = i$, the eigenvectors are $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ i & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & i \end{bmatrix}$.  Let $V = E_i$ be the eigenspace to $Ad_{h_1}$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $i$ (so $V$ is just the span of these two $X$s).

I claim that $Ad_{h_2}:V\rightarrow V$.  In fact, this is general:  if $A$ and $B$ commute, then $B$ maps any eigenvector of $A$ to a new eigenvector of $A$ with the same eigenvalue. For, if $Ax = \lambda x$, then $ABx = BAx = B\lambda x = \lambda B x$.

We now wish to find eigenvalues of $Ad_{h_2}|_V$.

Let $Y = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ ai & bi\end{bmatrix}$ be an arbitrary element of $V$.  Then $Ad_{h_2}Y = \begin{bmatrix} b & -a\\ bi & - ai\end{bmatrix}$.

We see that $Y$ is an eigenvector of $Ad_{h_2}$ with eigenvalue $\mu$ iff $$\begin{align} b &=& \mu a \\ -a &=& \mu b\\ bi &=& \mu a i \\ -ai &=& \mu bi\end{align}$$

Again, this implies that $\mu = \pm i$.  Choosing $\mu = i$, we see that $Y = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & i \\ i & -1\end{bmatrix}$ is both in $V$ and is an eigenvector for $Ad_{h_2}$.

This implies that $span\{Y\}$ is an eigenspace for both $Ad_{h_1}$ and $Ad_{h_2}$, both with eigenvalue $i$.  Thus, if $\lambda(h_1) = \lambda(h_2) = i$ and we extend $\lambda$ to all of $\mathfrak{h}$ by linearity, then $Y\in \mathfrak{g}_\lambda$.

From here, you find the other 3 eigenspaces by considering the cases $\eta = \pm i$ and $\mu = \pm i$ separately.  (I've just done the case where we choose plus signs for both).

Comment: Okay by letting

Comment: @Jason, Okay by letting h1 = {u=1,v=0} and h2 = {u=0, v=1}, then taking ad_hi of a generic element of g I get two matrices.  They both have the same eigenvalues, $\pm \frac{\sqrt{-b^2-c^2-d^2-e^2\pm \sqrt{\left((c+d)^2+(b-e)^2\right) \left((c-d)^2+(b+e)^2\right)}}}{\sqrt{2}}$ , with a,b,c,d,e,f the entries in my matrix for g.  What do you mean by reading them off and using linearity to get the lambda functionals

Comment: You still need to split things into eigenspaces.  This should lead to writing $\mathfrak{g}$ as a direct sum of vector spaces, each of which is an eigenspace for both $Ad_{h_1}$ and $Ad_{h_2}$.

Comment: Then, if, say $v\in E$ where $E$ is an eigenspace, you'd have $Ad_{h_i}v = \lambda_i v$ for some $\lambda_i$.  This gives $\lambda:\mathfrak{h}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where $\lambda(h_i) = \lambda_i$, and then you extend by linearity.

Comment: @Jason, But I have 4 different eigenvalues and only two basis elements for h

Comment: For a given eigenspace, you only have one eigenvalue for each basis element.

Comment: @Jason, Sorry, I'm completely confused now.  I only have the two basis elements for $\mathfrak{h}\$, $h_1$ and $h_2$.  They both have the same eigenvalues (4), but different eigenvectors (so 8 total).  How exactly do I continue from here?

Comment: I've added an example, let me know if you need more.